# Http 404 error for media links on Nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, reverse-proxy, cdn

I need to show media (images & videos) links from external cdn from my vps that has nginx web server. My summary config on nginx.conf :

```html
upstream video_balancer {
        server                  res.cloudinary.com;
        }

server {
        listen                  80; 
        server_name             video.XXXXX.com;  
        return                  301      https://$host$request_uri; 
        }

server {
        listen                  443      ssl; 
        ssl                     on;
        server_name             video.XXXXX.com;
        root                    /var/www/video/html/;
        ssl_ciphers             'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/XXXXX.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/XXXXX.key;
        ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_verify_client       off;
                                                                                                       
    location / {    
        try_files               $uri $uri/ 404;
        proxy_method            GET;                                                                                                
        proxy_redirect          off;                                                                                                
        proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;                                                                      
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;                                                               
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                 
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;                                                                    
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port        443;                                                                        
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Ssl         on;                                                                         
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-HTTPS       "on";                                                                       
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;                                                                                                
        proxy_http_version      1.1;                                                                                                
        proxy_pass              http://video_balancer$request_uri;                                                           
        }                                                                                                                           
}
```

When I try sample below link, I got 404 Not Found  error:

```
https://video.XXXXX.com/mediaclub/video/upload/v1527154870/news.mp4
```

and related access logs:

```
X.X.X.X - - [24/May/2018:14:53:42 +0430] "GET /mediaclub/video/upload/v1527154870/news.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by redirect, for same issue in future:

```
location ^~ /path/ {
          rewrite ^ http://res.cloudinary.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```